# Python selenium send_keys not working in chrome

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I'm new to python coding. And I'm trying to play around with python and Selenium in chrome. And I have this code where I'm trying to move a webpage up and down. But it isn't working.

```
body_elem = browser.find_element_by_tag_name('body')

for __ in range(3):
    body_elem.send_keys(Keys.END)
    sleep(2)
    body_elem.send_keys(Keys.HOME)
    sleep(2)
```

All I get is this long error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "selenium_test.py", line 34, in <module>
    body_elem.send_keys(Keys.HOME)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 479, in send_keys
    'value': keys_to_typing(value)})
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 628, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 312, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
```

Anybody got an idea of whats is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely because of the fact that *the DOM tree or the `body` element signature itself changed after the first "down" move*. One straightforward way to approach the problem would be to "re-find" the element constantly:

```
for _ in range(3):
    browser.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.END)
    sleep(2)
    browser.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.HOME)
    sleep(2)
```

Comment: Great that works. But isn't that the same as using body_elem = browser.find_element_by_tag_name('body')?

Comment: @user3403590 glad it worked. No, every time you issue "find element" command - there is a JSON over HTTP request sent to the "webdriver" which allows us to "refresh" the body web element instance we are working with in the Python code..